# Breaking up the rules to call a strategy from the strategy algorithm

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

So let's say I have this class

```cs
var intItems = new List<int> { 200, 2, 3 };
var stringItems = new List<string> { "Hello", " ", "World!" };
var intItems2 = new List<int> { 10, 2, 3 };

var consolidator = new Consolidator();
var s = consolidator.ConsolidateToString(intItems);
Console.WriteLine(s);

s = consolidator.ConsolidateToString(stringItems);
Console.WriteLine(s);

s = consolidator.ConsolidateToString(intItems2);
Console.WriteLine(s);


public class Consolidator
{
    public string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(items);
        string consolidatedString = string.Empty;

        if (items is IEnumerable<int> subtract && subtract.Any(i => i > 100))
        {
            consolidatedString = subtract.Aggregate((total, value) => total - value).ToString();
        }
        else if (items is IEnumerable<int> intItems)
        {
            consolidatedString = intItems.Aggregate((total, value) => total + value).ToString();
        }
        else if (items is IEnumerable<string>)
        {
            consolidatedString = string.Concat(items);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No valid consolidation found.");
        }

        return consolidatedString;
    }
}
```

I get the results

```
195
Hello World!
15
```

This design works but has issues.  For one, hard to test and it can become pretty complex with many `if` conditions.  It will also become a maintenance hell once you start adding pieces.

So strategy 2

```cs
var intItems = new List<int> { 200, 2, 3 };
var intItems2 = new List<int> { 10, 2, 3 };
var stringItems = new List<string> { "Hello", " ", "World!" };
var consolidationStrategies = new List<IConsolidator> { new SubtractIntConsolidator(),  new IntConsolidator(), new StringConsolidator() };

var consolidatorStrategy = consolidationStrategies.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.CanHanldeType(intItems));
if (consolidatorStrategy is null)
{
    throw new Exception("No valid consolidation found.");
}

var s = consolidatorStrategy.ConsolidateToString(intItems);
Console.WriteLine(s);

consolidatorStrategy = consolidationStrategies.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.CanHanldeType(stringItems));
if (consolidatorStrategy is null)
{
    throw new Exception("No valid consolidation found.");
}

s = consolidatorStrategy.ConsolidateToString(stringItems);
Console.WriteLine(s);

consolidatorStrategy = consolidationStrategies.FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.CanHanldeType(intItems2));
if (consolidatorStrategy is null)
{
    throw new Exception("No valid consolidation found.");
}

s = consolidatorStrategy.ConsolidateToString(intItems2);
Console.WriteLine(s);


public interface IConsolidator
{
    bool CanHanldeType<T>(IEnumerable<T> items);

    string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items);
}

public class IntConsolidator : IConsolidator
{
    public bool CanHanldeType<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return items is IEnumerable<int>;
    }

    public string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var intItems = items as IEnumerable<int>;
        return intItems.Aggregate((total, value) => total + value).ToString();
    }
}

public class StringConsolidator : IConsolidator
{
    public bool CanHanldeType<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return items is IEnumerable<string>;
    }

    public string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var intItems = items as IEnumerable<string>;
        return string.Concat(items);
    }
}

public class SubtractIntConsolidator : IConsolidator
{
    public bool CanHanldeType<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        return items is IEnumerable<int> intTypes && intTypes.Any(i => i > 100);
    }

    public string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var intItems = items as IEnumerable<int>;
        return intItems.Aggregate((total, value) => total - value).ToString();
    }
}
```

The results

```
195
Hello World!
15
```

Awesome, it works and has a much better design.

The next day another person runs the program and gets

```
205
Hello World!
15
```

Oh no, they switched the arrays from

```cs
var consolidationStrategies = new List<IConsolidator> { new SubtractIntConsolidator(), new IntConsolidator(), new StringConsolidator() };
```

to

```cs
var consolidationStrategies = new List<IConsolidator> { new IntConsolidator(), new SubtractIntConsolidator(), new StringConsolidator() };
```

This seems to be a really fragile design.  The other issue is the logic to call the strategy is hidden inside the strategy itself. So anyone creating a new strategy would need to look at each strategy to see if their strategy overlaps with any current ones. If it does, you would need to have the arrays in the correct order. I think this makes it a bit hard to troubleshoot and leaves too much room for error.

So strategy 3

```cs
var intItems = new List<int> { 200, 2, 3 };
var intItems2 = new List<int> { 10, 2, 3 };
var stringItems = new List<string> { "Hello", " ", "World!" };

var consolidatorFactory = new ConsolidatorFactory();
var consolidatorStrategy = consolidatorFactory.GetConsolidator(intItems);

var s = consolidatorStrategy.ConsolidateToString(intItems);
Console.WriteLine(s);

consolidatorStrategy = consolidatorFactory.GetConsolidator(stringItems);
s = consolidatorStrategy.ConsolidateToString(stringItems);
Console.WriteLine(s);

consolidatorStrategy = consolidatorFactory.GetConsolidator(intItems2);
s = consolidatorStrategy.ConsolidateToString(intItems2);
Console.WriteLine(s);

public class ConsolidatorFactory
{
    public IConsolidator GetConsolidator<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        IConsolidator consolidator = null;
        if (items is IEnumerable<string>)
        {
            consolidator = new StringConsolidator();
        }
        else if (items is IEnumerable<int> intTypes && intTypes.Any(i => i > 100))
        {
            consolidator = new SubtractIntConsolidator();
        }
        else if (items is IEnumerable<int>)
        {
            consolidator = new IntConsolidator();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("No valid consolidation found.");
        }

        return consolidator;
    }
}

public interface IConsolidator
{
    string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items);
}

public class IntConsolidator : IConsolidator
{
    public string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var intItems = items as IEnumerable<int>;
        return intItems.Aggregate((total, value) => total + value).ToString();
    }
}

public class StringConsolidator : IConsolidator
{
    public string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var intItems = items as IEnumerable<string>;
        return string.Concat(items);
    }
}

public class SubtractIntConsolidator : IConsolidator
{
    public string ConsolidateToString<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var intItems = items as IEnumerable<int>;
        return intItems.Aggregate((total, value) => total - value).ToString();
    }
}
```

The results

```
195
Hello World!
15
```

Awesome, it works.  However, we're back to a class with a complex `if` condition, which is not great when it comes to maintainability.

So the question is, is there a better approach?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Note, `Enumerable.Sum` usually performs better than `Enumerable.Aggregate`.

I can suggest two solutions that both significantly improve class design:

### Solution 1

Implement a collection type based *Strategy* pattern: one strategy for a particular collection type.
The advantage is that every strategy type decides on its own how to handle the input type. This eliminates an external switch and enforces the *Single Responsibility* and *Open-Close* principles.

**Program.cs**

```cs
static void Main()
{
  var intItems = new List<int> { 200, 2, 3 };
  var intItems2 = new List<int> { 10, 2, 3 };
  var stringItems = new List<string> { "Hello", " ", "World!" };
  var consolidator = new Consolidator();

  if (ConsolidationStrategyFactory.TryCreateStrategy(out IConsolidationStrategy<int>? int32Strategy))
  {
    string result = consolidator.Consolidate(intItems, int32Strategy);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    result = consolidator.Consolidate(intItems2, int32Strategy);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }

  if (ConsolidationStrategyFactory.TryCreateStrategy(out IConsolidationStrategy<string>? stringSrategy))
  {
    string result = consolidator.Consolidate(stringItems, stringSrategy);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
}
```

**Consolidator.cs**

```cs
public class Consolidator
{
  public string Consolidate<TInput>(IEnumerable<TInput> inputValues, IConsolidationStrategy<TInput> strategy) => strategy.Consolidate(inputValues);
}
```

**ConsolidationStrategyFactory.cs**
A helper class to get a supporting strategy for a particular type.

```cs
public class ConsolidationStrategyFactory
{
  private static IEnumerable<IConsolidationStrategy> RegisteredStrategies { get; }

  static ConsolidationStrategyFactory()
  {
    ConsolidationStrategyFactory.RegisteredStrategies = new List<IConsolidationStrategy>
    {
      new Int32ConsolidationStrategy(),
      new StringConsolidationStrategy()
    };
  }

  public static bool TryCreateStrategy<TInput>(out IConsolidationStrategy<TInput>? strategy)
  {
    strategy = RegisteredStrategies.FirstOrDefault(strategy => strategy.CanHandleType<TInput>()) as IConsolidationStrategy<TInput>;
    return strategy is not null;
  }
}
```

**IConsolidationStrategy.cs**

```cs
public interface IConsolidationStrategy
{
  bool CanHandleType<TDesired>();
}
```

**IConsolidationStrategy.cs**

```cs
public interface IConsolidationStrategy<TInput> : IConsolidationStrategy
{
  string Consolidate(IEnumerable<TInput> inputValues);
}
```

**ConsolidationStrategy.cs**

```cs
public abstract class ConsolidationStrategy<TInput> : IConsolidationStrategy<TInput>
{
  public bool CanHandleType<TDesired>() => typeof(TInput) == typeof(TDesired);
  public abstract string Consolidate(IEnumerable<TInput> inputValues);
}
```

**Int32ConsolidationStrategy.cs**

```cs
public class Int32ConsolidationStrategy : ConsolidationStrategy<int>
{
  public override string Consolidate(IEnumerable<int> inputValues) 
    => (inputValues.Any(value => value > 100) 
      ? SubtractValues(inputValues) 
      : SumValues(inputValues))
    .ToString();

    private int SumValues(IEnumerable<int> inputValues) => inputValues.Sum();
  private int SubtractValues(IEnumerable<int> inputValues) => inputValues.Aggregate(0, (result, value) => result - value);
}
```

**StringConsolidationStrategy.cs**

```cs
public class StringConsolidationStrategy : ConsolidationStrategy<string>
{
  public override string Consolidate(IEnumerable<string> inputValues)
    => string.Concat(inputValues);
}
```

---

### Solution 2

Implement a type based *Builder* pattern. It has the same benefits in terms of implementing SOLID principles, but requires less code (implementation and usage). It also has better performance if you need to inspect the values, for example the `int` case, because you can inspect the added value immediately when adding it. This eliminates the costly enumeration to identify for example a value greater than '100'. The usage of course changes too.

**Program.cs**

```cs
static void Main()
{
  var intConsolidationBuilder = new Int32ConsolidationBuilder();
  intConsolidationBuilder
    .Add(200)
    .Add(2)
    .Add(3);
  string result = intConsolidationBuilder.Consolidate();
  Console.WriteLine(result);

  intConsolidationBuilder.Clear();
  intConsolidationBuilder
    .Add(10)
    .Add(2)
    .Add(3);
  result = intConsolidationBuilder.Consolidate();
  Console.WriteLine(result);

  var stringConsolidationBuilder = new StringConsolidationCollectionBuilder();
  stringConsolidationBuilder
    .Append("Hello")
    .Append(" ")
    .Append("World!");
  result = stringConsolidationBuilder.Consolidate();
  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Int32ConsolidationBuilder.cs**

```cs
public class Int32ConsolidationBuilder
{ 
  private IList<int> InputValues { get; }
  private bool IsSubtractingValues { get; set; }

  public Int32ConsolidationBuilder()
  {
    this.InputValues = new List<int>();
  }

  public Int32ConsolidationBuilder Add(int value)
  {
    this.InputValues.Add(value);
    this.IsSubtractingValues |= value > 100;

    return this;
  }

  public void Clear() => this.InputValues.Clear();

  public string Consolidate() 
    => (this.IsSubtractingValues 
        ? SubtractValues(this.InputValues) 
        : SumValues(this.InputValues))
      .ToString();

  private int SumValues(IEnumerable<int> inputValues) => inputValues.Sum();
  private int SubtractValues(IEnumerable<int> inputValues) => inputValues.Aggregate(0, (result, value) => result - value);
}
```

**StringConsolidationBuilder.cs**

```cs
public class StringConsolidationBuilder
{
  private StringBuilder InputValues { get; }

  public StringConsolidationBuilder()
  {
    this.InputValues = new StringBuilder();
  }

  public void Add(string value) => this.InputValues.Append(value);

  public string Consolidate() => this.InputValues.ToString();
}
```